# When converting binary data to JSON in python how to get rid of extra lines and whitespaces?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, binary-data

I currently have binary data that looks like this:

`test = b'Got [01]:\n{\'test\': [{\'message\': \'foo bar baz \'\n                                  "\'secured\', current \'proposal\'.",\n                       \'name\': \'this is a very great name \'\n                               \'approves something of great order \'\n                               \'has no one else associated\',\n                       \'status\': \'very good\'}],\n \'log-url\': \'https://localhost/we/are/the/champions\',\n \'status\': \'rockingandrolling\'}\n`

As you can see this is basically JSON.
So what I did was the following:
`test.decode('utf8').replace("Got [01]:\n{", '{').replace("\n", "").replace("'", '"')`

This basically turned it into a string, and get it as close to valid JSON as possible. Unfortunately, it doesn't fully get there, because when I convert it to a string, it keeps all these stupid spaces and line breaks. That is hard to parse out, with all the `.replace()`s I keep using.

Is there any way to make the binary data that is being outputted and decoded to produce all 1 line allowing to parse the string, and so I can turn it into JSON format

I have also used a regex to this specific case, and it works, but because this binary data is generated dynamically every time, it may be a tad different where the line breaks and spaces are. So a regex is too brittle to catch every case.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what is generating this data? ';

Comment: the problem here is that you have object keys mapping to values, and those values are in some cases not a single string.... instead, they appear to be arbitrarily long sequences of strings which may be delimited by either single or double quotes and presumably need to be joined. Processing that will require a push-down automata, since it requires balancing pairs of unescaped single/double quotes until a `,` or `}` is encountered that is outside of the body of a string. Is this an actual sample of the data you are dealing with? I can't imagine what program is giving output that is so sloppy.